# Set the default value of Symfony embeddend form input

Tags: forms, symfony, default-value

With Symfony2, I'm unable to to set the default values of an embedded form.

This is my base form (Parent):

```
...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('child', new ChildType());
        ...
}
...
```

This is my embedded form (Child):

```
...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('name');
        ...
}
...
```

And this is my embedded entity (Child):

```
...
class Child
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'Test';
    }
}
...
```

This is the controller code to create the form with the parent entity:

```
...
    $parent = new Parent();
    $deceasedForm = $this->createForm(new ParentType(), $parent);
...
```

As you can see, the Child.name input should be set to "Test", but this is not working, it stay blank. Whereas Parent.xyz inputs do take  the default value...

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you show the controller code? I suspect you send an object to the view that doesn't have an initialized `Child`.

Comment: I updated the post with the controller snippet.

Comment: OK? I understood what you said just after sending my last comment. Now I have `$this->setChild(new Child());` in my parent constructor... Thanks!

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: As you solved your problem, can you please post your solution as an answer and accept it? It avoids having tons of questions with no answers all over SO :)

Comment: You would also document that for yourself (which helps also keeping the memory) *and* you will get upvotes over time. And the question can be marked as solved. Answering FTW.

Comment: OK, I answered my question, but I'm not arleady able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered @cheesemacfly, the child has to be initialized before creating the form.
So there is 2 ways to do so:

1. In your controller, where you create the form, initialize a Child and give it to your form:

   ```
   ...
   $parent = new Parent();
   $parent->setChild(new Child());
   $deceasedForm = $this->createForm(new ParentType(), $parent);
   ...
   ```
2. In your Parent contructor initialize the Child

   ```
   public function __construct()
   {
       ....
       $this->child = new Child();
       ....
   }
   ```